# How to use logical And in VoiceXML

Tags: conditional-statements, logical-operators, voicexml

I am try to use "logical and" in voicexml(with Viecore extensions)

Here is my code:

```
<if cond="(menuChangeOn == 'YES')&&(businessGroup == '<%=Viecore.ABCCompany.DataAccess.Constants.CURRENT_MODULE.Main_Number%>')">
```

The "&&" seems to cause trouble while the voice xml file is parsed.

What's the best practice to resolve this common problem?

Comment: BTW, you are using server templates which is not pure VoiceXML.  You should rather post the resulting VoiceXML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It XML, so you must use XML entities `&amp;` for the ampersand symbol. So instead of `&&`, use `&amp;&amp;`.

Comment: Yes, that helps address my issue. Thanks a lot.